# Add a Property to Entity Class in ViewModel

Tags: c#, inheritance, properties, overloading, derived-class

I have a profile with a EntityCollection of ProfileUser. In this Class I have a Profile_ID ald a Profile relation and a User_ID but no USer relation, because User is in another Database.

In a Datagrid I want to access via User.Username

I tried this, but ofc it doesnt work...

```
public EntityCollection<ProfileUser> ProfileUsers
    {
        get
        {
            if (profile != null) return profile.ProfileUser;
            else return null;
        }
        set
        {
            profile.ProfileUser = value;
        }
    }
```

and here my custom Class

```
public class ProfileUserExtended : ProfileUser
{
    public Operator User
    {
        get
        {
            return OperatorManager.GetByGuId(this.User_ID);
        }
    }
}
```

Of course I cannot construct the derived class by the base class. But I need this Operator be part of the collection I bind to...

I hope you understand my problem and can help.

**edit:**
This Converter solved the Problem for me:

```
public class OperatorConverter:IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!(value is Guid)) return null;
            if (!(parameter is string)) return null;

            var guid = (Guid)value;
            var par = (string)parameter;

            var op = OperatorManager.GetByGuId(guid);
            if (op == null) return null;

            var prop = op.GetType().GetProperty(par);
            if (prop == null) return null;

            return prop.GetValue(op, null);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw (e);
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();

    }
}
```

In XAML:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Path=User_ID,Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=operatorConverter},ConverterParameter='Name'}" IsReadOnly="True" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are three ways to achieve several bindings similar to what you need to do.

1) a wrapper class:

```
public class ProfileUserWrapper : DependencyObject
{
    public ProfileUserWrapper(ProfileUser thebrain) { TheUser = thebrain; }

    public ProfileUser TheUser { get; private set; }

    public Operator User { get { if (_user != null)return _user; return _user = OperatorManager.GetByGuId(TheUser.User_ID); } }
    private Operator _user = null;
}
```

Now, instead of having a `public EntityCollection<ProfileUser> ProfileUsers` you may expose for example `IEnumerable<ProfileUserWrapper>`:

```
public EntityCollection<ProfileUser> ProfileUsers // your original code
{
    get{ if (profile != null) return profile.ProfileUser; else return null;}
    set { profile.ProfileUser = value; }
}

public IEnumerable<ProfileUserWrapper> ProfileUsers2
{
    get { return ProfileUsers.Select(user => new ProfileUserWrapper(user));
}
```

then bind to the ProfileUsers2, and some of your bindings should be changed from "Address" to "TheUser.Address", but this almost surely will work.

2) second, a smart-converter, for example:

```
public class OperatorPicker : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, System.Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var pu = value as ProfileUser;
        if (pu != null)
            return OperatorManager.GetByGuId(pu.User_ID);
        return null;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, System.Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

It almost couldn't be simplier to write. Now you can use the converter in the XAML binding:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <myextra:OperatorPicker x:Key="conv1" />
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <ListBox x:Name="lbxFirst" ItemsSource="{Binding ProfileUsers}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Margin="5" Text="{Binding User_ID}" />
                    <TextBlock Margin="5" Text="{Binding Login}" />
                    <TextBlock Margin="5" Text="{Binding Address}" />
                    <TextBlock Margin="5" Text="{Binding Path=., Converter={StaticResource conv1}}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

But this way, you will get the `Operator` object it self. It will be hyper-hard to allow you to bind to the properties of operator returned in such way, as the Binding already has path fixed at ".", and you cannot change that, as the Converter must be passed a ProfileUser instance..

3) third, most complex but completely working without any wrappers is based on **an attached property, converter and a two bindings**, but you could do it also on two attached properties and one change callback. I prefer the former way, so here it is:

```
public class DummyClass : DependencyObject
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TheOperatorProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "TheOperator", typeof(Operator), typeof(DummyClass),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender)
    );

    public static Operator GetTheOperator(DependencyObject elem) { return (Operator)elem.GetValue(TheOperatorProperty); }
    public static void SetTheOperator(DependencyObject elem, Operator value) { elem.SetValue(TheOperatorProperty, value); }
}

    ... xmlns:myextra="clr-namespace:...." ....

<Window.Resources>
    <myextra:OperatorPicker x:Key="conv1" />
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <ListBox x:Name="lbxFirst" ItemsSource="{Binding ProfileUsers}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel x:Name="aparent" Orientation="Horizontal"
                            myextra:DummyClass.TheOperator="{Binding Path=., Converter={StaticResource conv1}}">
                    <TextBlock Margin="5" Text="{Binding User_ID}" />
                    <TextBlock Margin="5" Text="{Binding Login}" />
                    <TextBlock Margin="5" Text="{Binding Address}" />
                    <TextBlock Margin="5"
                               Text="{Binding Path=(myextra:DummyClass.TheOperator).OperatorCodename, ElementName=aparent}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

Please note that there is a new binding at the level of StackPanel. This one can be placed **anywhere** in the data template, even on the textbox itself. Note how it translates a ProfileUser into an Operator via a converter. The `Path=.` is not required, but I added it so the exact meaning of the binding is shown. Note how the last textbox binding is specified: it is a binding to that attached property (via element-name), not to the original data!

This time I've tested everything and it works on my side with no DependencyObject inheritance on the ProfileUser. it is satisfied by the `DummyClass` inheritance. If you try this, please drop me a note as usual :)

Comment: Wow, you are totally amazing! I try this out tomorrow and give you a feedback!

Comment: Hey,
your solution 2 turned out to be the best for my situation, I added the final Code in the first Post. Thank you so much for the time you spent helping me!

Comment: No problem:) However, if you already have the converter, I really encourage you to try also the third kind. This is because with the converter you will have a hard time (or ugly code) if you want to bind to many sub-properties of the `Operator` class. And it will be even worse if you want to make 2-way bindings. #3 is only a little more code, but is more "clean" with respect to how Bindings want ot work :) Anyways, use whatever suits your current needs. See you.

Comment: The only reason why a converter is the perfect solution in my case, is the OneWay Binding. I only need to display this additional information, without saving them. And also I dont need to play with or change the ProfileUser Class, which would be impossible or at least so much work...
Solution 3 I'll try also, but im very happy with solution 2 at the Moment.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT: this is quite a good solution, but it turned out that it requires** that the target data object inherits from **DependencyObject** which is not the case. Here, the data object probably inherits from EntityObject and this cannot be changed, as it is the source DAO object:)

Having said that, lets play with Attached Properties:

---

You sometimes can solve it quite easily with [Attached Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011.aspx). The binding engine can not only bind to normal properties or dependency properties. Actually it can bind to 5 or more things, and the easiest one of them are the Att.Props.

An attached property is a "virtual" or rather a "fake" property (lets name it "IsZonk") defined in some random class (call it ABC) , but registered in a special way so that the binding engine treats it as if it was present on your specified target class (let's say XYZ). Any attempt to access IsZonk on XYZ via bindings will cause the binding engine to bounce the request to the ABC class. Moreover, the resulting method call in the ABC class will be given the exact XYZ object that the request originated from.

This way you can easily **extend** existing objects with new data or even new functionalities without even modifying them. It is very like "static extension methods" added to C# in the 3.5 version.

```
namespace Whatever {

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        lbxFirst.DataContext = new MyModel();
    }
}

public class MyModel
{
    public IEnumerable<ProfileUser> ProfileUsers
    {
        get
        {
            var tmp = new[]
            {
                new ProfileUser{ User_ID = "001", Login = "Adelle", Address = "123 Shiny Street" },
                new ProfileUser{ User_ID = "002", Login = "Beatrice", Address = "456 Sleepy Hill" },
                new ProfileUser{ User_ID = "003", Login = "Celine", Address = "789 Rover Dome" },
            };

            tmp[0].SetValue(ProfileUserExtras.UserProperty, new Operator { RelatedUser = tmp[0], OperatorCodename = "Birdie", PermissionLevel = 111 });
            tmp[1].SetValue(ProfileUserExtras.UserProperty, new Operator { RelatedUser = tmp[1], OperatorCodename = "Twin", PermissionLevel = 222 });
            tmp[2].SetValue(ProfileUserExtras.UserProperty, new Operator { RelatedUser = tmp[2], OperatorCodename = "Trident", PermissionLevel = 333 });

            return tmp;
        }
    }
}

public class ProfileUser : DependencyObject
{
    public string User_ID { get; set; }
    public string Login { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    //- Operator User {get{}} -- does NOT exist here
}

public class Operator
{
    public ProfileUser RelatedUser { get; set; }
    public string OperatorCodename { get; set; }
    public int PermissionLevel { get; set; }
}

public static class ProfileUserExtras
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty UserProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "User",             // the name of the property
        typeof(Operator),   // property type
        typeof(ProfileUserExtras), // the TARGET type that will have the property attached to it

        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender) // whatever meta you like
    );
}

}
```

The last thing is to use it in XAML:

```
.... xmlns:myextra="clr-namespace:Whatever" ....

<ListBox x:Name="lbxFirst" ItemsSource="{Binding ProfileUsers}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Margin="5" Text="{Binding User_ID}" />
                <TextBlock Margin="5" Text="{Binding Login}" />
                <TextBlock Margin="5" Text="{Binding Address}" />
                <TextBlock Margin="5" Text="{Binding Path=(myextra:ProfileUserExtras.User).OperatorCodename}" />
                <TextBlock Margin="5" Text="{Binding Path=(myextra:ProfileUserExtras.User).PermissionLevel}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Please pay attention to the notation of an attached property in the binding. It **must be enclosed in parenthesis** and also almost always will need a namespace prefix, elsewise the binding engine will look for something else and somewhere else. By adding the parens you indicate that this property is an 'attached property' instead of normal one.

Comment: Hey thanks for the quick reply, I can imagine how this shoukd work. Im looking forward for your code example, becasue yet I have no clue how to implement this ;)

Comment: I've just added the example. Here's also a one article on [binding to attached properties](http://geekswithblogs.net/NewThingsILearned/archive/2008/01/15/binding-to-an-attached-property.aspx) but mind that he returns a simple value from the proeprty so there is no dot-property after the parens in the binding expression. This article describes a few things, but I encourage you to search and experiment. This is a very fun topic to play with! Especially the "Attached behaviours" you may stumble upon at some time:)

Comment: The only thing that bothers me is to whever the ProfileData has to be a DependencyObject to allow to 'attach', or not.. I'm sorry, I really do not remember, so all of this may turn out to be unusable for EntityObjects.. In such case, you'd have to either wrap wrap the data object in some simple "view" class, or you'd have to play hard with Type model and propertydescriptors.. let me know if you succeeded in the attached way!

Comment: Hey, tank you for the answer! I tried binding to User as an Attached Property like this: `Binding="{Binding (balls:AttachedProperties.User).UserName}"` but Im getting an Binding Error: `BindingExpression path error: '(balls:AttachedProperties.User)' property not found on 'object' ''ProfileUser' (HashCode=12444132)'. BindingExpression:Path=(balls:AttachedProperties.User).UserName; DataItem='ProfileUser'`. Do you know a solution for this? The Binding DataContext is ProfileUser and I registered the Dependency Property of the operator type to ProfileUser, but it wont even get into the getter.

Comment: Hey, I found out, that adding a `Path=`solves that problem, but now I get the message, that `User Property is not found on AttachedProperties`. I mean... of course, because i registered it with `ProfileUser`, so I need to bind with `Path=User.UserName` instead?

Comment: The correct path for the binding is `Path=(MyHelperClassName.TheAttachedProperty).OtherSubProperties`. You need the parens. If the class is not in "default" namespace, you need to add proper `prefix:` to it. If this still does not work, then it would indicate that the attached property failed to register it self properly and it simply is not found on that object. This could be an effect of missing the inheritance to DependencyObject what I noted few times above. Do you now, or have you tried making the ProfileUser temporarily ihnerit from it instead of EntityObject/whateverelse?

Comment: Yes I tried that, but then i cannot bind it to `Profile.ProfileUser` because it's another class then. Im Pretty sure I made the binding correctly, so it must have something to do with the `DependencyObject`.
It's really tricky, but thanks for your detailed help already!

Comment: Hm. I'll check that once I get back to the other computer with VS on it

Comment: Hey, i found the solution: The binding is now correct. When I register User to Profile User I can access it via `Path=User.UserName` but now I receive the error Message, that `ProfileUser` cannot be converted to `DependencyObject` :/

Comment: Aaw.. Thats not good :( the attached properties are then a dead end, or add nothing. Next thing I'd recommend is to revert to a trivial wrapper like `class Dummy : DependencyObject { public ProfileUser Profile {get;set} public Operator { get {...} } }` and expose such objects to the View instead of ProfileUser directly. All  the bindings are still simple. However, if you cannot do that for some reason, then the next way to force the binding engine to notice "an extra" property is to play with custom type descriptors. This is not an easy thing though and may need small edits to the ProfileUser.

Comment: I've just found a note on MSDN that "attached properties are settable on any object". I'll try to recreate your problem case and update the code.

Comment: Not true. The target of the Attached Prop must inherit from DependencyObject, period. Eh. If you just need to be able to bind, then  the next quickest attempt is to do it via a specialized converter. but if you need to have a logical property - you are left with type descriptors. Pick one of the ways and drop me an note, I'll try to drop you some links then

Comment: I've corrected the code examples. The reason why you could not access the att.props was ... that the properties were **not set** on the target objects. I'm terribly sorry for the confusion. The GetUser() method is not a callback!!! It was only a helper method. To set the vvalue, a Binding must be established or a DObj.SetValue must be called.